# Python requests.Session.__init()__ mounts HTTPAdapter twice

Tags: python, python-requests

The following is from **requests Advanced Usage**:

> Requests ships with a single Transport Adapter, the HTTPAdapter. This
>   adapter provides the default Requests interaction with HTTP and HTTPS
>   using the powerful urllib3 library. Whenever a Requests Session is
>   initialized, one of these is attached to the Session object for HTTP,
>   and one for HTTPS.
>
> The mount call registers a specific instance of a Transport Adapter to
>   a prefix. Once mounted, any HTTP request made using that session whose
>   URL starts with the given prefix will use the given Transport Adapter.

1. If I wanted to mount a custom Transport Adapter, in other words an HTTPAdapter with it own set of retry_codes and retry_max attempts, would it not be better to unmount all existing mounted HTTPAdapters before mounting a new custom adapter?
2. Is there a way to verbosily track a Transport Adapter like HTTPAdapter, such as what retry_code is it performing retry and what retry attempt count is being performed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session.mount method is used to set the dictionary index for the prefix in the property session.adapters. The default session [will mount 2 adapters](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L357-L360). You could implement a new class based on HTTPAdapter to achieve the behaviour you're asking for. Since the retry logic is handled in the send() method, you could call the base class send method, catch RetyError exceptions and handle them separately.

```
import requests


class CustomAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    # custom __init__?
    def send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):
        try:
             requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
        except requests.exceptions.RetryError:
             # do your thing


def load_custom(session):
    session.adapters['http://'] = CustomAdapter()
```

Look at the [Exception handling code in requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L482) and also the requests_mock implementation for examples